# Why does the `call` is faster than the `callvirt` in IL?

Tags: instance, clr, virtual-functions, cil

Why does the `call` is faster than the `callvirt` in IL?

I am exploring the **C# via CLR** book and I come across the following excerpt:

> The call IL instruction can be used to call static, instance, and virtual methods. When the call
>   instruction is used to call a static method, you must specify the type that defines the method
>   that the CLR should call. When the call instruction is used to call an instance or virtual
>   method, you must specify a variable that refers to an object. The call instruction assumes that
>   this variable is not null. In other words, the type of the variable itself indicates which type
>   defines the method that the CLR should call. If the variable’s type doesn’t define the method,
>   base types are checked for a matching method. The call instruction is frequently used to call a
>   virtual method nonvirtually.
>
> The callvirt IL instruction can be used to call instance and virtual methods, not static
>   methods. When the callvirt instruction is used to call an instance or virtual method, you
>   must specify a variable that refers to an object. When the callvirt IL instruction is used to call
>   a nonvirtual instance method, the type of the variable indicates which type defines the method
>   that the CLR should call. When the callvirt IL instruction is used to call a virtual instance
>   method, the CLR discovers the actual type of the object being used to make the call and then
>   calls the method polymorphically. In order to determine the type, the variable being used to
>   make the call must not be null. In other words, when compiling this call, the JIT compiler
>   generates code that verifies that the variable’s value is not null. If it is null, the callvirt
>   instruction causes the CLR to throw a NullReferenceException. This additional check means
>   that the callvirt IL instruction executes slightly more slowly than the call instruction.
>   Note that this null check is performed even when the callvirt instruction is used to call a
>   nonvirtual instance method.

And I can not wrap my head around that part: `This additional check means that the callvirt IL instruction executes slightly more slowly than the call instruction.`. Both the `call` and the `callvirt` assume that the object is not null. Hence, both of them should check that the object is not null. And as a result the speed should be the same.

Could someone explain it in a foolproof manner?

Comment: It is extremely inaccurate, the author tries too hard to avoid talking about the way a processor executes C# code.  It never executes IL, it executes the machine code that is produced by the just-in-time compiler.  The processor also has two versions of the CALL instruction, a direct call that has an address as the argument and an indirect call whose operand says where the address is stored.  The latter is used for a virtual call.  The extra read that is necessary to retrieve the address makes a virtual call slower, it can cause a pipeline bubble.  The NRE check is actually for free.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. You comment help me understand the matter. If you post it as an answer, then I will accept it. And could you, please, elaborate the pipeline point? What pipeline are you talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@HansPassant answer to you already about the time difference between direct and indirect calls.

I want to add something that related directly to your question:

> Both the call and the callvirt assume that the object is not null. Hence, both of them should check that the object is not null. And as a result the speed should be the same.

Pay close attention to the text.

For `call` instruction:

> The call instruction assumes that this variable is not null

And for `callvirt` instruction:

> the JIT compiler generates code that verifies that the variable’s value is not null

The thing is that `call` instruction not generating the null check. Yes as @Hans points out, the null check is only one assembly instruction, and it's almost for free, but it's important to know about the missing null check.

It's legal to use `call` or `callvirt` for both calls - virtual and non-virtual.
What's happening is that for all calls except those the compiler can be sure that the `this` type isn't null or there is no `this`, `callvirt` will be used, in rest of the cases, `call` will be used.

All of this is just from the Compiler\IL point of view. What happening later, is as @Hans wrote, direct call when it's possible or indirect call when it's required. But this will happen anyway whether there was a `call` or a `callvirt`.

For more info see [IL Call Vs. Callvirt Instruction](https://mycodingplace.wordpress.com/2014/04/22/call-vs-callvirt-instruction/) - You will find there more relevant links.

Comment: What kind of the pipeline was mentioned in the comments section?